# everytime i try to install a package i get the following

Tags: python

```
pip install readline
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\gamin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\gamin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
Collecting readline
  Using cached readline-6.2.4.1.tar.gz (2.3 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error: this module is not meant to work on Windows
      [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\gamin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\gamin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Does "this module is not meant to work on Windows" not explain what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Install pyreadline instead of readline:**

```
$pip install pyreadline
```

or

```
$python -m pip install pyreadline
```

Go back to your python file and type:

```
from pyreadline import Readline
readline = Readline()
```

As a result, you can use **readline on Windows** .

Comment: readline is not available in Windows the way it is available in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

It simply isn’t meant for windows. That’s the whole answer. Pyreadline is the package for windows, you can use it for similar results